# How do I duplicate a serial terminal?

Tags: terminal

This may be an XY problem, but I would like to clone a serial terminal such as /dev/ttyUSB0 into two terminals. The input from either muxed into the real terminal, and the output fed to both. Is there a tool to achieve this/is this a possibility?

I often work with embedded hardware over serial using a small terminal emulator [dterm](http://www.knossos.net.nz/resources/free-software/dterm/). I would like to keep that interactive terminal open at all times, but also run command sequences using [expect](http://www.tcl.tk/man/expect5.31/expect.1.html) on it. Say, to reboot and stop at the U-Boot prompt for example.

I imagine a tool to be used like this:

```
$ teeterm /dev/ttyUSB0
Clone successful: /dev/pts/3 and /dev/pts/4 available.
$ dterm /dev/pts/3 115200
```

And in another shell:
`$ ./uboot (which spawns and interacts with dterm /dev/pts/4 115200)`

Comment: use [screen](https://www.gnu.org/software/screen/)

Comment: I have a small C program that implements a bi-directional pipe between two newly created pseudo-terminals that could be easily adapted to your problem (too lazy to do the adaption myself). Would that help you?

Comment: @dirkt That would absolutely help, is the source open and online somewhere?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using dirkt's posted example code as a base, I put together a real utility for this. It is [available on Github](https://github.com/kcghost/teeterm).

I ended up on a usage of:

`teeterm dterm /dev/ttyUSB0 115200
(in another shell) dterm pty0
(in another shell) dterm pty1`

The two pseudoterminals both have access to the command process I/O.
The most important aspects of the utility are a [forkpty](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Pseudo_002dTerminal-Pairs.html) call to control a child process via a pseudoterminal (that is not made available to the user), along with [openpty](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Pseudo_002dTerminal-Pairs.html) and [select](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/select.2.html) calls to create the two pseudoterminals and monitor all three for inputs.

Answer (score 1):

As requested, a small C program that bi-directional pipe between two newly created pseudo-terminals. No, that doesn't answer the question, but it can be easily adapted to do so. It's not very long, so here's the code. Licence is "do whatever you want with it".

```
/* ptycat (ptypipe? ptypair?)
 *
 * create a pair of pseudo-terminal slaves connected to each other
 *
 * Link with -lutil
 *
 * Alternative: socat PTY,link=COM8 PTY,link=COM9
 *
 */

#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

#include <errno.h>
#include <termios.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <pty.h>

#undef max
#define max(x,y) ((x) > (y) ? (x) : (y))

/*
  (void)ioctl(STDIN_FILENO, TIOCGWINSZ, &win);

*/

/* TODO: make symlinks, unlink on atexit */

static uint8_t buf[BUFSIZ]; /* BUFSIZ from stdio.h, at least 256 */
static char *log_dir = NULL;

void logdata (char *dir, uint8_t *data, int n) {
  if (dir != log_dir) fprintf (stdout, "\n%s", dir);
  log_dir = dir;
  for (; n > 0; n--, data++) fprintf (stdout, " %02x", *data);
  fflush (stdout);
}

int main (int argc, char* argv[])
{
  char name[256]; /* max namelen = 255 for most fs. */
  fd_set rfd;

  struct termios tt;
  struct winsize ws;
  int master[2], slave[2];
  int n, nfds, cc;

  if (tcgetattr (STDIN_FILENO, &tt) < 0)
  {
    perror("Cannot get terminal attributes of stdin");
    exit(1);
  }
  cfmakeraw (&tt);
  for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
  {
    if (openpty (&master[i], &slave[i], name, &tt, NULL /*ws*/) < 0)
    {
      perror("Cannot open pty");
      exit(1);
    }
    puts(name);
  }

  for (;;) {
    FD_ZERO(&rfd);  
    FD_SET(master[0], &rfd);
    FD_SET(master[1], &rfd);
    nfds = max(master[0], master[1]) + 1;
    n = select(nfds, &rfd, 0, 0, NULL);
    if (n > 0 || errno == EINTR)
    {
      if (FD_ISSET(master[0], &rfd))
      {
        if ((cc = read(master[0], buf, sizeof(buf))) > 0)
        {
          (void) write(master[1], buf, cc);
          logdata (">>>", buf, cc);
        }
      }

      if (FD_ISSET(master[1], &rfd))
      {
        if ((cc = read(master[1], buf, sizeof(buf))) > 0)
        {
          (void) write(master[0], buf, cc);
          logdata ("<<<", buf, cc);
        }
      }
    }
  }
  /* This is never reached */
  return 0; 
}
```